# Vimrc using a variable inside a cmap

Tags: vim

I'm writing a piece of vimscript to manage sessions. I would like to let the user configure which directory they would like the sessions to be saved in, ie:

```
let g:sessions_dir = "~/.vim/sessions"
```

I have a number of commands that let the user create and load sessions. But I would also like to provide a `cmap` that let's the user tab through the sessions in that directory.

```
cmap GSo :wa<CR> :source ~/.vim/sessions
```

This works, and the user can hit TAB to cycle through their session files. However, I want to use that `g:sessions_dir` variable in the cmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `cmap` within an `execute`. For example,

```
exe "cmap Gso :wa<CR> :so ".g:sessions_dir
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<C-r>=` here:

```
cnoremap GSo :wa<CR> :source <C-r>=g:sessions_dir<CR>
```

(last `<CR>` is for `<C-r>=`, it won’t launch the command).

Answer (score 0):

another example:

```
let g:work_dir='C:\...\'  " define a new global variable work_dir
:cmap <F1> Explore <C-r>=g:work_dir<CR>
```

when you click F1 on the command-line, then output
`:Ex C:\...\`

or

```
:cmap WK_DIR Explore <C-r>=g:work_dir<CR>
```

Once you were typing `WK_DIR` on the command line, the result is the same as above.